# Getting Empty variable in curl using php

Tags: php, curl, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am trying to execute a url using Curl and i am getting empty output.

However, if we copy-paste Same url in Browser, we are getting value

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json
```

However, when i try same to get value in php using Curl, i am getting Null

php code

```
 <?php

$BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql"; 



    // Form YQL query and build URI to YQL Web service
    $yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env';
    $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" .$yql_query. "&format=json";


    // Make call with cURL
    $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $json = curl_exec($session);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);exit;

?>
```

Any suggestion ??????

Comment: Check the output of [curl_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: double check the question when you post. we were not able to see the full code, when you posted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is working for me

```
<?php

$BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql"; 
    $query = 'select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28"YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"%29&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json';
    echo $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" .$query;


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    print_r($content);
?>
```

Query must be properly encoded .

Check it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json_decode` for this.

Check manuals -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Check this working code now --(working atleast my end ) --

```
<?php

$yql_query_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json"; 

    // Make call with cURL
    $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $json = curl_exec($session);

$jsonnew=json_decode($json,true);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($jsonnew);

?>
```

Comment: print_r($json);exit;
 This is empty

Comment: @shail actually the URL you mentioned is fetching data in json format so you need to actually decode the data..check the link which i just posted

Comment: Since the variable "$json" isempty, there is no use of json_decode

Comment: @jason decode will work once we will get output in jason. Since the output of curl is empty, jason_decode is also empty

Comment: @shail the code is working fine..i guess you are having problem in query try this and let me know then ---   $query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json';

Comment: @suresh is code is working fine :), please check :). Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I got the error.

I have to Use "urlencode" function to encode Url before using it In CURL

i.e.

instead of

```
$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" .$yql_query. "&format=json";
```

I have to use

```
$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" .urlencode($yql_query). "&format=json";
```

and It works :) lol